# Given $f'(x)=(x-a)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}$,to investigate for extreme values at $x=a$ and $x=b$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If $(x-a)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}$,where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers,is the derivative of a function $f$ ,then show that $x=b$ gives a minimum but $x=a$ gives neither maximum nor minimum

My attempt:
$$f'(x)=(x-a)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}$$
$$f''(x)=(x-a)^{2n-1}(x-b)^{2m}[2n(x-b)+(2m+1)(x-a)]$$
But at $x=a$  and $x=b$,$f''(x)=0$

How do I proceed?

Comment: you must try higher derivatives

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubnerWouldn't that also give 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to proceed (assuming $a\neq b$).

You could show that the sign of the derivative does not change as $x$ increases through $a$, but does change as $x$ increases through $b$.

This can be done without computing further derivatives.

---

To illustrate:

So about $x=a$ constrain $|\epsilon|\lt |a-b|$ and write $x=a+\epsilon$

$$f'(a+\epsilon)=\epsilon^{2n}(a+\epsilon-b)^{2m+1}$$

Now show that the second term is non-zero and has the same sign whatever $\epsilon$ is (within the constraint), and that the first term is positive for $\epsilon \neq 0$. So near $x=a$ the derivative does not change sign.

And then do the same thing near $b$ with $\epsilon$ similarly constrained.

Comment: Can you show how to do that?

Comment: @PiGamma I've illustrated how to go about this - you'll have to work out some of the details yourself.